# Segmentation Error on swift 3.02 Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: swift

The following code generates a segmentation error:

```
  extension Int
    {
        static prefix func++(i:Int)->Int{

            return i+1;
        }

        static prefix func--(i:Int)->Int{
            return i-1;
        }
    }


    infix operator <-;

    class DynamicList<T>: RangeReplaceableCollection, MutableCollection, BidirectionalCollection
    {

        var length:Int;
        var arr:Array<T>?;
        var startIndex:Int{
            return 0;
        }
        var endIndex:Int{

            return length;
        }

        subscript(i:Int)->T{
            get{
                return arr![i];
            }
            set{
                arr![i] = newValue;
            }
        }

        func index(after i: Int) -> Int{
            return ++i;
        }

        func index(before i: Int) -> Int{
            return --i;
        }

        required init(){
            length = 0;



        }



        static func <- (left: inout DynamicList<T>, right: DynamicList<T>){

        }


        /* func replaceSubrange<C>(_ subrange: Range<Self.Index>, with newElements: C) where C : Collection,
            C.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element  */



        func replaceSubrange<C>(_ subrange: Range<DynamicList.Index>, with c: C)
        where C : Collection, C.Iterator.Element == DynamicList.Iterator.Element{








        }


    }
```

My intent here is to have the generic class `DynamicList<T>`

adopt three protocols:

`class DynamicList<T>: RangeReplaceableCollection, MutableCollection, BidirectionalCollection`

as indicated in the code above but it generates segmentation error.

However, when I replace `MutableCollection` with `Collection`, code above complies.

If I remove `BidirectionalCollection`, the code above compiles with no segmentation error.

Is it not possible to adopt all 3:

- RangeReplaceableCollection
- MutableCollection
- BidirectionalCollection

at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you get a segmentation error during the compilation or when you run it. If the latter, please say where it occurs. If the former, you need the stack trace and you need to report the compiler bug to swift.org.

Comment: It's a compile time error. The code just aims to mimick the array structure which also  adopts all 3 protocols. Not quite sure why my code is generating a segmentation fault 11 at compile time.